# Write correct cycle for nested JSON data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json.net

I have some data:

```
{
    "id": 56,
    "number": "82467",
    "date": "2021-08-19",
    "exams": [
        {
            "type": "fff123",
            "stamp": "2021-08-19R17:00:17",
            "review": [
                {
                    "code": "1118",
                    "value": "3",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "type": "nnn123",
            "stamp": "2021-08-19R12:00:47",
            "review": [
                {
                    "code": "1120",
                    "value": "1",
                },
                {
                    "code": "1121",
                    "value": "2",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please tell me ,how I can get  for `"type": "nnn123"`, two value because now I get just one only first.I do something wrong in cycle, but I don't know what .How I can to get two values ?

```
                {
                    "code": "1120",
                    "value": "1",
                },
                {
                    "code": "1121",
                    "value": "2",
                }
```

, please maybe someone knows how I must correct write my code

```
        def get_object(self):
                number = self.kwargs['number']
                type = self.kwargs['type']
                obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset.filter(number=number))
                data = obj.exams
                filtered_exams = list(filter(lambda x: x["type"] == type, data))
                for i in filtered_exams[0]['review']:
                    return i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that in your for loop (`for i in filtered_exams[0]['review']`) you return i so only the first element in `filtered_exams[0]['review']`.

Just replace

```
for i in filtered_exams[0]['review']:
    return i
```

With

```
return filtered_exams[0]['review']
```

Comment: Keczif ,I write filtered_exams['review'] I got error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Could you maybe describe what you want to do? get_object() should return single object in a form of a djano model. The problem is that you want to return the list with 2 elements. Maybe the better approach will be to return the whole object in the get_object() method (so only 'return obj') and then extract the exams and filter them later.

Comment: I must return exactly  this 2 values  when user type in url , for example http//result/82467/nnn123 , it's my task (( and I spended 2  days for it's and now I get only one - it's task provides what user wants to have data results of  'type ' thermometer - get exactly this data (all))for this results and this been API for outsiders companies  , sorry for my bad English , I compare learn English and DRF/JSON :)

Comment: possible is return 2 values separately of object list ?

Comment: Maybe return dict then, try:

'return {i: filtered_exams[0]['review'][i] for i in range(len(filtered_exams[0]['review']))}'

You will receive:

'{0: {'code': '1120', 'value': '1'}, 1: {'code': '1121', 'value': '2'}}'

Comment: when I try return dict I get another error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 17; 2 is required

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: def get_object(self):
                number = self.kwargs['number']
                type = self.kwargs['type']
                obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset.filter(number=number))
                data = obj.exams
                filtered_exams= list(filter(lambda x: x["type"] == type, data))
                for i in filtered_exams[0]['review']:
                    print(i)
                return {i: filtered_exams_data[0]['review'][i] for i in range(len(filtered_exams[0]))

Comment: I get IndexError: list index out of range, sorry I can't` give  all code -there are limitations